# Incomplete image is written using fwrite()

Tags: c++, image-processing

I was writing a code to read and write an image file, but my code works fine except for only one fourth of the image is written when using fwrite()...Please help me find out where i've mistaken.Thanks in advance.
PS I'm a newbie in this field.

This is my code for the read and write functions.
Please ignore any silly things I might have coded to get the work done.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
int c,numberOfCols,numberOfRows,HighVal,totalPx,header;
int** a;
int doneReading = FALSE;
char * string;
unsigned char * image;

//Read Image

int readImage(char **argv){

  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen (argv[1],"rt");
  if (pFile==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
  else {
  string = (char *)calloc(256,1);
  while (!(doneReading) && !feof (pFile)) {
    c=(char)getc (pFile);

    switch(c){
        case 'P':
         c=(char)getc (pFile);
        switch(c){
                case '1':
                    header=1;
        std::cout<<".pbm white n black";
            break;
            case '2':
            header=2;   
            std::cout<<".pgm greyscale";
            break;
            case '3':
                header=3;
            std::cout<<".ppm rgb";
            break;
           }
         c=(char)getc (pFile);
        if(c==0x0A) ungetc(c,pFile) ;
        break;
        case '#':
            fgets(string,256,pFile);
        std::cout<<"File you entered is "<<string<<"\n";
        break;
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
        ungetc(c,pFile);
        fscanf(pFile,"%d %d %d",&(numberOfCols),&(numberOfRows),&(HighVal));
        doneReading=TRUE;

        std::cout<<"Done";
        std::cout<<"\nNo. of columns: "<<numberOfCols<<"\nNo. of Columns: "<<numberOfRows<<"\nMaximum Intensity: "<<HighVal<<"\n";

        break;
       }
       totalPx=numberOfCols*numberOfRows*1;
       image=(unsigned char *)malloc(totalPx);
        fread(image,1,totalPx,pFile);

  }

  std::cout<<"Image read from "<<argv[1]<<"...\n";
}
return totalPx; 
}

//Write Image

void writeImage(char **argv,int pixels){

    FILE *fOut;
fOut=fopen(argv[2],"wt");
if (fOut==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
  else {
       fprintf(fOut,"P%d \n%d %d \n%d",header,numberOfCols,numberOfRows,HighVal);
       fwrite(image,1,pixels,fOut);
       std::cout<<"Image Written on "<<argv[2]<<"...";
  }
}

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{

    int pixels;
    pixels = readImage(argv);
    writeImage(argv,pixels);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: Please avoid posting code with pictures.

Comment: You should post your code as text in the question, not as an image.  Also, please reduce it to a [mcve].  People will be able to better help you if you post the shortest program needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fwrite() File Corruption C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976992/fwrite-file-corruption-c)

Comment: Don't forget to check return values. malloc() can return NULL. You are missing format 4, 5 and 6, the binary version of 1, 2 and 3. Comments I believe can be longer than 256 chars. And have you considered files with \r in them? Not sure if the ppm standard allows them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be with the value returned from `readImage()`. It's returning the number of pixels without taking into account the size of a pixel. This line:

```
totalPx=numberOfCols*numberOfRows*1;
```

returns the number of pixels, but a pixel can be 1, 2, 4 or more bytes. Assuming your image data is RGBA, then you need to multiply that by 4 in the call to either `writeImage()` or `fwrite()`.